# Error: "invalid use of non-static member function" while calling a function from my own class-method

Tags: library, class

I'm having a bad time trying to call a correctly-working expression (`ultra[currentSensor].ping_timer(echoCheck)`) from an own class method (`myclass::run`) instead of from `void loop()`.

I'm getting the following compiler error:
**"invalid use of non-static member function"**.

If I call `ultra[currentSensor].ping_timer(echoCheck)` directly from `void loop()` it gives me no error, so I may be missing something.

Here's the (shortened) piece of code which is generating the error:

```
#include <NewPing.h>

#define ULTRA_NUM      3
#define MAX_DISTANCE 200

class myclass {
  public:

    void run();
    void echoCheck();

    unsigned int distance[ULTRA_NUM];
    uint8_t currentSensor = 0;
};

NewPing ultra[ULTRA_NUM] = {
  NewPing(4, 5, MAX_DISTANCE),
  NewPing(6, 7, MAX_DISTANCE),
  NewPing(8, 9, MAX_DISTANCE)
};

void myclass::run() {
// ....
      ultra[currentSensor].ping_timer(echoCheck);  // Compiler error
  }

void myclass::echoCheck() {
  if (ultra[currentSensor].check_timer())
    distance[currentSensor] = ultra[currentSensor].ping_result
}
```

`ping_timer()` is defined as it follows:

```
void NewPing::ping_timer(void (*userFunc)(void), unsigned int max_cm_distance) {
    if (max_cm_distance > 0) set_max_distance(max_cm_distance);

    if (!ping_trigger()) return;
    timer_us(ECHO_TIMER_FREQ, userFunc);
}
```

I hope any of you can help me!

Thanks in advance,

Eduardo

---

**Edit**:
What I am trying to do is to adapt [this example](https://bitbucket.org/teckel12/arduino-new-ping/wiki/Help%20with%2015%20Sensors%20Example%20Sketch) (from NewPing Arduino Library) so that the sonar ping (`sonar[currentSensor].ping_timer(echoCheck)`) is done from a class method, and not from `void loop()`.

Comment: [This](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12983) might help. There is a discussion about calling a class function from an ISR.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `echo_check` isn't `void echo_check()` but `void echo_check(myclass *this)` because it's a member function of a class.

You can make the whole thing static (along with `run()`) by:

```
class myclass {
    public:
        static void run();
        static void echo_check();
};

static void myclass::run() {
    .... 
}

void myclass::echo_check() {
    ....
}
```

And then you call:

```
myclass::run();
```

instead of instantiating an object.

Comment: mm seems to solve the problem, but I'm getting now compiler errors wherever the class members are used (and also inside the class definition): "invalid use of member 'Ultrabot::_xxxxxxx' in static member function"

Comment: A static function can only call other static functions or global normal functions, or functions of other classes that are defined as static members.

Comment: So now I have compiling functions which can't make what they are supposed to? :/

Comment: I don't know since you never bothered to show us your *real* code, only some tiny snippet.

Comment: It's not about bothering to do it or not, it's about trying not to bother you with all my partially built code. I hope it's more clear now with the edit.

Comment: Well, the answer I gave addresses the question you asked. Since that then breaks unspecified code in some unspecified way then I cannot help you further.

Comment: The edit doesn't make anything any clearer at all, no. That is precisely what I assumed you were doing. You need to either re-work your code so it can be all static, or re-work NewPing so it can accept the right kind of function as a callback and not have any of it static. Take your pick.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

I moved the event handler out of the class, and made it static void.

Then the code compiled properly

D